# Vuejs, import component file issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a files structure issue that I am trying to fix when referencing components into other components as imports.

The current files setup I have looks like this...

[image]

I am working on the file called security_passphrase.vue and within that file I reference 2 files to import as I need to use them there.

```
import dropdown from '../components/vue_form/dropdown.vue'
import formbutton from '../components/vue_form/form_button.vue'
```

The compiler cannot find the modules I am trying to load.

```
 Error: Cannot find module '../../components/vue_form/dropdown.vue' from 'C:\wamp64\www\merchant-backend-new\merchant-backend\resources\assets\js\components\vue_form\concertina_form'
```

> Error: Cannot find module '../../components/vue_form/form_button.vue'
> from
> 'C:\wamp64\www\merchant-backend-new\merchant-backend\resources\assets\js\components\vue_form\concertina_form'

I have tried different ways to make this work but no success. The files I am trying to import are outside of the folder where the file is I am working with.

> /concertina_form/security_passphrase.vue /vue_form/form_button.vue
>
> /vue_form/dropdown.vue

Help will be great :)

Comment: You are moving out two folders you just need to use `import dropdown from '../dropdown.vue'`

Comment: Thanks @samayo works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

```
import dropdown from '../dropdown.vue'
import formbutton from '../form_button.vue'
```

Should be the correct way to import these files, using `../` goes down one directory which will take you from the concertina_form directory to the vue_form directory.